# Need help understanding this piece of code

Tags: jquery, json, yql

I apologize in advance if this is the wrong place to post this sort of thing, but here we go:

Here is the code I'm currently implementing on my webiste (Thanks to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) for this code)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url=\'https://stackoverflow.com/\'and xpath=\'//div[@id="question-mini-list"]//h3//a\'&format=json&callback=?';    
    $.getJSON( url, function(data){
        $.each(data.query.results.a, function(){ 
            $('#stack').append('<td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com'+this.href +'">'+this.content+'</a></td>')           
        })
    })
});
```

I hate to use code I don't fully understand, So here is my questions:

In the 'var url' in the query, he uses @id="question-mini-list". I looked in the html of stackoverflow, and there is nothing by that name (closest I got was a class named 'question-hyperlink'), so why does that work?

Second: In the 'each', data.query.results.a I don't see 'query' or 'results' used anywhere else, so how I know to use those?.

Last question: at the end of your 'url' why 'callback=?' ?

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: If you do `console.log(data)` you can see where `query.results` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be amazed what you can find when you Google something!

I don't know anything about XPath, but I noticed that the `@id` you're asking with was associated with something about XPath:

```
xpath=\'//div[@id="question-mini-list"]
```

I Googled 'XPath' and found a page that explains that `@id` is shorthand for selecting the 'id' attribute of the context node.

Now, I do happen to know a little bit about the next two points in your question, but if I didn't, I'm sure Google would have told me that `.getJSON()` returns a data object.  From the query, I can deduct that the object's structure is something like:

```
data: {
    query: {
        results: {
            a: // something
        }
    }
}
```

You would either know in advance to use `data.query.results.a` or you can discover the data object's structure using the console.

Google would also point me to documentation about JSON callbacks that explain that question mark syntax.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help! :) I have however googled a fair bit about this, and I already knew what you wrote about @id, but like I wrote in my question: I didn't find the id-attribute named "question-mini-list" anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you view source on `stackoverflow.com` you'll see this:

   `<div id="question-mini-list">`

   `<h3><a href="/questions/....">...</a></h3>`

   `...`
2. The [YQL result JSON object](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/response_structure.html) looks like:

   `{ query: { results: { a: [ ... ] } } }`
3. Apparently [`callback` needs to be set](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_url.html) to get JSON output.